# ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE error while hosting my frontend on AWS using cloudfront and backend on a EC2 behind a loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssl-certificate, load-balancing

I am trying to host my frontend on AWS using cloudfront and backend on a EC2 behind a classic loadbalancer. I have imported my SSL certificate in ACM. Using ACM the certifcate has been installed on Cloudfront and classic Loadbalancer.

Cloudfront configuration:

```
Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs) = mydomain.com
SSL Certificate = mydomain.com (xxx-yyy-zzz............)
```

Classic loadbalancer Configuration:
The load balancer is hosted on api.mydomain.com and SSL certificate installed using ACM.

[image]

[image]

Security group inbound rules configuration:
[image]

EC2 is running a Nodejs server listening on port 80. I haven't installed SSL certificate on EC2 because it was not mentioned in AWS documentation.

The home page opens up but when I try to login I get an error:

```
LoginSignUp.js:84 OPTIONS https://api.mydomain.com/user/signin net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
```

So the browser is blocking backend response because it is not secure. Do I need to install SSL certificate on EC2 also? Or did I make any configuration mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears from your question that your SSL certificate is for `mydomain.com` and you are trying to request `api.mydomain.com`

Create a new ACM certificate that includes `api.domain.com` as either the domain name or as a Subject Alternative Name (SAN).

At a glance, the rest of the build looks correct.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error. I completely overlooked it. I have requested for a wildcard certificate via AWS. Will mark it as answer once that works.